# Java client and Erlang server?

Tags: java, networking, erlang

I am about to write a client-server application (a simple game) and I want to use Erlang for the server side and Java for the client side. How should I make the connection between client and server? I have never worked with network programming before...

I think that "sockets" is the thing that I should use, am I right? In that case, could I use Java's sockets-class to send/recieve messages on the client and some corresponding sockets-module in Erlang on the server? Or do I have to have some kind of Java receiver on the server and then translate to Erlang? Is sockets some general protocol sent over the network that all languages interprets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to learn.

1. Sockets are low level and you will need design a protocol.
2. HTTP Rest API is more general, requires web server (yaws for example)
3. or Jinterface  Erlang<->Java bridge

http://www.slideshare.net/dennisbyrne/integrating-java-and-erlang-with-jinterface-presentation

Comment: Hm, If I say that I want to learn the networking way that is best suitable for a bigger game (Like real multiplayer games...), does that make my decision easier? 
I looked at JInterface and that seems to be a good way to communicate between the languages. Does that do both network communication and language communication at the same time?

Comment: Have not checked, but looks like it support network + wire protocolol.

If it is a pet project go for lowel level sockets, you'll gonna learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, Erlang provides a module for Socket programming that you can use. Go with your option number one.

But is such low level programming is a must for you? If not for your game, then consider creating a REST API. It is HTTP after all. Thus you can achieve:

> general protocol sent over the network that all languages interprets

Comment: I had no idea about what REST API was, but I googled it and found out that it is some kind of http or web communication api. My first taught was that this is just suitable for web applications (running in a web browser) but I might be wrong? I'm wondering, just to clarify that it is a standalone game I want to write (not a web application). But as I said in the first post, I have not worked with network programming before so I have no clue at all...

Comment: @theva That is what I say: "If it is makes sense to use REST API in your game". I don't know about your game. If you want to do socket programming, then you can do it: Java-Erlang, Erlang-Java, Java-Java or Erlang-Erlang.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to sockets and HTTP for creating

> some general protocol sent over the network that all languages interprets

is something like [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) or other interface description languages (IDL). While it doesn't support *all* languages, it does support both Java and Erlang.